# Constraining simple design

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, quartus, timing-analysis, sdc

I am stydying the Quartus II + TimeQuest Analyzer. The documentation is abreast, the examples are not that of, and explanations for beginners are scarce.

Here's the simple code:

```
module test_project (
    input wire clock,
    input wire reset,
    output reg data = 1'b1
);

reg [1:0] div = {2{1'b0}};
always@(posedge clock)
    div[1:0] <= div[1:0] + 1'b1;

wire clk_enable = (div[1:0] == 2'b00);
    
always@(posedge clock or negedge reset) begin
    if(!reset) data <= 1'b1;
    else if(clk_enable)
                data <= ~data;
end
```

the contents of SDC file is:

```
create_clock -name {clock} -period 229MHz [get_ports {clock}]
```

Here's timing report from TimeQuest:

[image]

for the following path:

[image]

The above was generated using "report timing" custom report dialog.

I do not understand why it shows only one path (while there're more paths in the design), and why it does not see that there's clock enable of 4 clocks. Whatever I put into multicycle command into SDC file, I do not get what I think must see - the constraint that data from launching adder will reach output `data` register for latching within 4 cycles of the `clock`.

What is the logic of doing this simple constraint for this scenario (and why)?

If it will be properly constrained in the SDC file, will Quartus try to fit having this constraint fulfilled with no violations, right?

Comment: It should be showing the worst-case timing path cz that's the slack we should be worried about. See detailed report to see all timing paths.

Comment: Why you didn't add multi-path constraint on data path?

Comment: I think from my question is clear that: I am not able to understand "detailed report", and that I can not add _proper_ pultipath constraint because I do not know how to do it. Can you give example to achieve the goal? And then explain it?

Comment: You should check the Altera tool guide, to find how to see the detailed timing report. What you have been shown is just summary of timing with critical path only.

Comment: Setting multipath should be straightforward. But your last question is not clear. Are you asking why we need constraints at all?

Comment: Everyone says it is straightforward and easy. Can you design proper SDC clause for it, and explain how it works?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did the answer solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your tool is showing only the *critical path*, i.e., the one with the worst slack. There must be specific command/option to see detailed timing report which shows all timing paths.

By the way, `create_clock` constraint sets up the basic clock constraint for Timing Analyser to synthesise and optimize the timing performance of the design. Since `clk_enable` has a time period of four times that of `clock`, and it enables `data` bus when it has to be driven, you can relax timing on its timing paths by taking advantage of multi-path timing constraints. For e.g., something like this:

```
set_multicycle_path -setup -end -to [get_registers data[*]] 4

set_multicycle_path -hold -end -to [get_registers data[*]] 3
```

This will multi-path constraint all timing paths to `data` registers with setup requirement = \$4\$ destination clock cycles. This setup constraint will by default move the hold timing edge to 3rd cycle, which is not the requirement you need. Hold should be analysed at the launching edge itself. So you should specify a hold constraint of \$3\$ destination clock cycles, which will move back the holding edge by \$3\$ destination clock cycles. In this case, all of the filtered timing paths are reg-to-reg paths which are fed back from `data` bus.