# create_generated_clock quartus for derived clock

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, intel-fpga, timing-analysis, sdc

I am working in a design that creates a 1Hz clock from 20MHz PLL out.

For that purpose, I have created a counter that switches its out when its value arrives to 10 000 000.
That 1Hz clock is used as input clock of a shift register connected to some LEDs.

Now I want to constrain that 1Hz clock.

For such purpose, I have added the next line in the sdc file:

```
create_generated_clock -name {clk_divider:inst5|q} -source [get_nets {inst1|altpll_component|auto_generated|wire_pll1_clk[0]}] -divide_by 20000 -duty_cycle 50 [get_nets {inst5|q}]
```

If I set the `divided_by` to the right value, 20_000_000, it does not work, and the design it is not synth'ed.  So i have set the value to  20_000, to erase the Quartus Timing Analysis warnings.

#### Question

Does this constraint make sense? Should I correct it and specify that it is a 1Hz clock somehow?

As the example is silly, I don't have timing issues, but in a more complicated designs, I guess this should be properly specified, so the P&R can put this part of the design in a place that does not bother the rest of the design.

Comment: Normally, it's not good practice to use a divided signal as a clock to other registers. Use the divided signal as a clock_enable, use registers with a clock enable, and clock these registers with the system clock. This keeps everything synchronous. If the registers are standalone and don't have to communicate with other system-clocked parts, you can generally get away with what you are doing, but using clock_enables is the correct way to use.

Comment: I understand. So you only need to enable the clock enable **just** in when 1Hz time arrived, so the registers receive the clock edge from the system clock when this happens, right?

Comment: Yes. At first glance it seems like you're using a lot more logic, and if you were building with discrete logic, you would be. But if your target is an FPGA, the fabric tends only to have registers with enables, so they're there, free to use without overhead.

Answer (score 2):

\$1\$ \$\text{Hz}\$ is a very slow clock, hence it's much much relaxed timing for setup, and meeting timing is not big issue here. You can constraint this slow clock correctly using `create_generated_clock` with the divider value \$20,000,000\$, and run timing analysis. I think if Altera throws warning for this, it is because of the tool limitation in analyzing clock edges that are so far apart due to the slow clock (computational limitation). See the discussion [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Quartus-Prime-Software/how-to-constrain-low-frequency-clocks/td-p/16798).

> So I have set the value to 20_000, to erase the Quartus Timing Analysis warnings

You are synthesising your design for \$1\$ \$\text{kHz}\$ by doing that. That doesn't change the fact that your design is actually going to run at \$1\$ \$\text{Hz}\$ on board. Providing wrong timing constraints is one way of getting the functionality to fail on board. However since your actual clock frequency of operation is \$1000\$x slower than that, and if the design passed for timing at \$1\$ \$\text{kHz}\$, then it should function on board at \$1\$ \$\text{Hz}\$ as well without timing failures.

Clocking FPGA fabric logic with internally generated clock using counters is a bad design technique. Instead, I would suggest you to make things simpler by generating a clock enable pulse at \$1\$ \$\text{Hz}\$ rate from \$20\$ \$\text{MHz}\$. And use this clock enable to gate your slow logic which is running in \$20\$ \$\text{MHz}\$. In this way, everything is in the same clock domain, and Synthesiser's job would also be simpler in meeting timing (See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244992/vhdl-creating-a-very-slow-clock-pulse-based-on-a-very-fast-clock/15245290#15245290)).

*Note: When you use clock enable, you can use multipath timing constraints to relax timing. See the answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/585227/constraining-simple-design/585280#585280)*.